# How to gracefully close a two-way WebSocket in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, websocket, iis-8

I have a [WebSocket](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.1.1) server that accepts a stream of binary data from a client and responds with another stream of text data for every 4MB read. The server uses IIS 8 and [asp.net web api](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618032/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-4-5-Part-2).

**Server**

```
public class WebSocketController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        HttpContext.Current.AcceptWebSocketRequest(async (context) =>
        {
            try
            {
                WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;

                byte[] requestBuffer = new byte[4194304];
                int offset = 0;

                while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    var requestSegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(requestBuffer, offset, requestBuffer.Length - offset);
                    WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(requestSegment, CancellationToken.None);

                    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    {
                        // Send one last response before closing
                        var response = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Server got " + offset + " bytes\n"));
                        await socket.SendAsync(response, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

                        // Close
                        await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
                        break;
                    }

                    offset += result.Count;
                    if (offset == requestBuffer.Length)
                    {
                        // Regular response
                        var response = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Server got 4194304 bytes\n"));
                        await socket.SendAsync(response, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                        offset = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log and continue
            }
        });

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
    }
}
```

The c# client uses the [ClientWebSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket(v=vs.110).aspx) class to connect to the server and send requests. It creates a task for receiving responses from the server that runs in parallel with the request sending. When it is done sending the requests it calls `CloseAsync` on the socket and then waits for the `Receive` task to complete.

**Client**

```
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebSocketClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                CallWebSocketServer().Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        static async Task CallWebSocketServer()
        {
            using (ClientWebSocket socket = new ClientWebSocket())
            {
                await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://localhost/RestWebController"), CancellationToken.None);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[128 * 1024];

                Task receiveTask = Receive(socket);
                for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i)
                {
                    await socket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None);
                }
               
                await socket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
                receiveTask.Wait();

                Console.WriteLine("All done");
            }
        }

        static async Task Receive(ClientWebSocket socket)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
                while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    var result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(recvBuffer), CancellationToken.None);
                    Console.WriteLine("Client got {0} bytes", result.Count);
                    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recvBuffer, 0, result.Count));
                    if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Close loop complete");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception in receive - {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the client blocks at the `CloseAsync` call.

What would be the correct way of gracefully closing the WebSocket in this scenario?

Comment: That is a very large receive buffer. When many client are connected, you need al lot of memory.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Figured this out.

**Server**

Basically, I had to call the `ClientWebSocket.CloseOutputAsync` (instead of the `CloseAsync`) method to tell the framework no more output is going to be sent from the client.

```
await socket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
```

**Client**

Then in the `Receive` function, I had to allow for socket state `WebSocketState.CloseSent` to receive the `Close` response from the server

```
static async Task Receive(ClientWebSocket socket)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[64 * 1024];
        while (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open || socket.State == WebSocketState.CloseSent)
        {
            var result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(recvBuffer), CancellationToken.None);
            Console.WriteLine("Client got {0} bytes", result.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recvBuffer, 0, result.Count));
            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Close loop complete");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in receive - {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it required to call [`ClientWebSocket.Dispose()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket.dispose?view=net-6.0)? Or can we reuse the same ClientWebSocket instance without create new one?

Answer (score 2):

I did some research using various combinations of the following code. The scenario is that the client sends data until the server closes the WebSocket.

**Server**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task Index()
    {
        using (WebSocket webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "ServerClose", new CancellationTokenSource(20_000).Token);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
static async Task SendDataToWebSocket(string webSocketUrl)
{
    ClientWebSocket webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
    try
    {
        await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(webSocketUrl), new CancellationTokenSource(5000).Token);
        ProcessCloseEvent(webSocket);

        while (true)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> data = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("something"));
            await webSocket.SendAsync(data, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    }
}

private static async void ProcessCloseEvent(ClientWebSocket webSocket)
{
    ArraySegment<byte> data = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1000]);
    var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(data, CancellationToken.None);
    Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}, CloseStatus: {1}, Data: {2}", result.Count, result.CloseStatus, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
    await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "ClientClose", CancellationToken.None);
}
```

I observed the following:

- `CloseAsync` works in pairs, meaning that the first side calls `CloseAsync` and waits until the other side calls it too.
- Bacause `CloseAsync` with `CancelationToken.None` will wait indefinitely, people prefer the use of `CloseOutputAsync` that seems not to be waiting for the other side to respond.
- Even though the WebSocket close event can be observed in the result returned by `ReceiveAsync` call, the `WebSocket.State` and `WebSocket.CloseStatus` only gets updated after `ReceiveAsync`.
- `CloseAsync` and `CloseOutputAsync` can be paired in any combination to respond to the WebSocket close event. Since it shouldn't be necessary to wait for a response when closing the WebSocket or know if the other side handled the close event, `CloseOutputAsync` should be better to use.
- Once the client responds with `CloseAsync` to the server's request, the `WebSocket.State` is changed to `Closed` and subsequent `SendAsync` and `ReceiveAsync` will throw an exception.
- If the client does not react to WebSocket close event and server disposes the WebSocket, the `SendAsync` at client side with throw an **IOException** with this message: "Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.."
- If the client does not react to WebSocket close event and server disposes the WebSocket, the `ReceiveAsync` at client side will throw an `WebSocketException` with the message: "The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake."
- After the server disposes the WebSocket, the client is able to send/receive a few messages without any exception, so there should be no concurrency problems between checking for close and exchanging data.
- Since `CloseAsync` waits for the other side, it can be used to determine if all sent data has been successfully received. This does not apply if both sides send and close at the same time.

**NOTE:** I have used .NET 6 for testing. The above observations may not apply in combinations with clients/servers written in other languages.

Answer (score -2):

i suggest you to look at these links:

asynchronous server:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

asynchronous client:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx

recently i implementled something similar with these links as an example. the methods "BeginReceive" (for server) and "BeginConnect" (for client) start each a new thread. so there won't be anything that blocks